# Excel show captain of team by cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, one with a database of players and teams.
In that database, I have a column named "Captain", if the player is captain, there should be a X in that cell.

In the other sheet, the result show be showed like this picture.

[image]

In this picture. I will be using the database for saving information.
And in result, it should look for example: 
"Looking for the Captain of Team1 and then showing out Name2"

I'm not sure how to process this and wondering if someone can help me with a code or similiar? Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused with your desired result (captains don't seem to match team), however you probably want to look into combining `INDEX` and `MATCH`

Comment: My bad, thanks for pointing it out! It should be more correct now. 
Hmmm.. Okay, gonna see If i can figure it out. Thanks. Such a beginner in this still

Comment: can a team have more than one captain? and the flip side is can a team have no captain assigned?

Comment: @ForwardEd there is only one captain for each team :). There is always one captain

Comment: actually the answer is not always.  I have dealt with system where there can be multiple team captains, in addition to co-captains/assistant captains.  While I personally disagree with such system, I thought I would clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example for you using a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$7=E2)*($C$2:$C$7="X"),0))
```

Entered as array formula, so hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> down and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If done correctly you'll see your formula capped between `{...}`.

Drag down..

Comment: Deleted my answer because I was doing the wrong way. I misunderstood Result with Database and did the opposite of what was needed. Your answer is the one that works properly (actually I upvoted before). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks alot fo the help and the code. It only prints "Name6", strange tho. I have the exact format as you just posted!

Comment: If you did the exact same it should work. Can you share the exact formula from cell F2